# Cannot find iso646.h in glibc

Tags: c, gcc, glibc

I downloaded several versions of `glibc` namely 2.18, 2.19, 2.20, 2.23 and am trying to find the file `iso646.h` but cannot find it. I thought it was a standard part of glibc so it should be there. Anyone know why it isn't there?

I have, however, found it on my local machine in the /usr/lib/gcc directory. So Im assuming it was installed with gcc. But I still don't know why I cant find it in the glibc sources. I'm pasting the contents of the one I found below:

```
/* Copyright (C) 1997-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

This file is part of GCC.

GCC is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 3, or (at your option)
any later version.

GCC is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the 
GNU General Public License for more details.

Under Section 7 of GPL version 3, you are granted additional
permissions described in the GCC Runtime Library Exception, version
3.1, as published by the Free Software Foundation.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License and 
a copy of the GCC Runtime Library Exception along with this program;
see the files COPYING3 and COPYING.RUNTIME respectively.  If not, see 
<http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */  

/*
 * ISO C Standard:  7.9  Alternative spellings  <iso646.h>
 */

#ifndef _ISO646_H
#define _ISO646_H

#ifndef __cplusplus
#define and     &&  
#define and_eq  &=
#define bitand  &
#define bitor   |
#define compl   ~
#define not     !
#define not_eq  !=
#define or      ||
#define or_eq   |=
#define xor     ^
#define xor_eq  ^=
#endif

#endif
```

***Edit:*** The only file I found (which kinda resembles iso646.h) in each of the glibc sources I downloaded(from gnu.org) was conform/data/iso646.h-data which looks like this:

```
#if !defined ISO && !defined POSIX && !defined XPG3 && !defined XPG4
macro and 
macro and_eq
macro bitand
macro bitor
macro compl
macro not 
macro not_eq
macro or
macro or_eq
macro xor 
macro xor_eq

#if !defined ISO && !defined ISO99 && !defined ISO11
allow *_t 
#endif
#endif
```

But since I dont how `macro` is defined here, or where it is defined, this file is incomprehensible to me.

Comment: have you checked the path  glibc/conform/data/iso646.h-data

Comment: @piyushjaiswal Yes I actually looked in the glibc/conform/data/iso646.h file before I asked my question, but since I didn't know how `macro` was defined, or in what file `macro` was defined in, I couldnt understand that file and didn't bother including it in the question. Please see the EDIT section I added to my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file is not part of libc, but the compiler.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Headers.html

```
$ find /|grep iso646.h
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/iso646.h
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include/iso646.h
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. Didn't know gcc includes its own headers when compiling programs. But as per [link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library the file iso646.h has been a part of the libc standard since 1995.... do you know the reason why glibc doesn't include it?

Comment: @jerry: See my answer. "The implementation" is the combination of the compiler and the library, and there are headers that the compiler maintainers have an easier time providing than the library maintainers.

Comment: Thanks @DevSolar +1 didnt know this agreement between library and compiler maintainers existed. Since I downloaded the glibc source directly from gnu.org and they dont include iso646.h at all in glibc, does this mean that the glibc maintainers will always assume that gcc will ALWAYS include it?

Answer (score 4):

In elaboration of Stian's answer on those files being part of the compiler, and where to find them:

---

There are various standard headers that are part of a so-called "freestanding implementation". They do `#define` and `typedef` only, and do not declare any actual functions; in other words, they are "header only" without any linkable code:

- `<float.h>`
- `<iso646.h>`
- `<limits.h>`
- `<stdalign.h>`
- `<stdarg.h>`
- `<stdbool.h>`
- `<stddef.h>`
- `<stdint.h>`
- `<stdnoreturn.h>`

It is quite possible, in some places even easier, to have these defined by the *compiler* instead of the *library*, because the compiler knows everything about its platform and the types it uses, their encoding, limits, stack layout and how to do variable argument lists, etc.

The compiler can provide the "correct" implementation for these headers without requiring any additional preprocessor "magic", which would be necessary if these headers were defined by the library.

Comment: Rather, the mentioned headers must be supported by all implementations (compilers), no matter if freestanding (embedded systems etc) or hosted (running on top of an OS).

Comment: @Lundin: The freestanding implementation is specifically defined as a subset of the hosted implementation. And implementation != compiler, implementation == (compiler + library).

Comment: Not really, they are different and have different rules for `main` etc. I believe you refer to 4/6: "The two forms of conforming implementation are hosted and freestanding. A conforming hosted implementation shall accept any strictly conforming program. A conforming freestanding implementation shall accept any strictly conforming program in which the
use of the features specified in the library clause (clause 7) is confined to the contents of the standard headers..." And then follows the list in your answer. So far you could say that freestanding is a subset, as far as headers go.

Answer (score 2):

As an added to Stian's answer, another way to find locations is using `gcc -E`

/* demo.c */

```
#include <iso646.h>

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Launch:

```
david@debian:~$ gcc -E demo.c

# 1 "demo.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "demo.c"
# 1 "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/iso646.h" 1 3 4
# 2 "demo.c" 2

int main(void)
{
 return 0;
}
```